# Finding Nth term using a generating function

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, wolfram-alpha

Good day everyone

I am in need of help, I was using an online program to solve a sequence, the name of the program is WolframAlpha and using it I was able to get the actual nth term that I was looking for several times. But in order to get that nth term the program used the following generating function

$$\frac{ z(-34z  ^ { 2  }  +77z-41)  }{ (z-1)  ^ { 3  }    }  +25$$

Note my sequence was **25,32,36,39,41** and gave me nth term ***42*** which is what I actually needed.
Now I need to find out how did the program get to find the nth using this generating function, I don't understand how -34z and 77z came to be.

Thank you while I wait for the answer

Comment: Could you share the link to your WA query? When I tried the same sequence, [I got](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=generating+function+of+sequence+beginning+25%2C+32%2C+36%2C+39%2C+41) $\frac{z(-27z^2+60z-32)}{(z-1)^3}+25$.

Comment: Hi J. G. Yes that's the right one I made a mistake

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps the fastest way to answer this question is to note that
\begin{align*}
f(z) = \frac{z(-34z^2 + 77z - 41)}{(z-1)^3} + 25 = -9 + \frac{25}{1-z} + \frac{11}{(1-z)^2} - \frac{2}{(1-z)^3}
\end{align*}

The coefficient of $z^n$ in the series expansion of  $(1-z)^{-1}, (1-z)^{-2}, (1-z)^{-3}$ are respectively $1, n+1, \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$. Therefore, the coefficient of $z^n$ in $f(z)$ is
\begin{align*}
-9\cdot\mathbb{I}_{\{n=0\}} + 25+ 11(n+1) - 2\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb{I}$ is the indicator function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment. I wish I could give a definitive answer, but what WA does is unclear.

That generating function implies a polynomial $n$th term. As with most choices of a sequence's first five terms, the lowest-order polynomial expression for the $n$th term that's correct for all data is quartic. You can see this by verifying these terms' third differences are two different values, $2,\,0$. It's likely WA determined the quartic first, then obtained its generating function (which will be a polynomial divided by $(z-1)^5$), so it's conceptually simplest to get the quartic directly.

The first differences are $7,\,4,\,3,\,2$; the second are $-3,\,-1,\,1$; the third are $2,\,0$; the only fourth difference is $-2$. If fourth differences are constant and $25$ is the $0$th term, the $n$th term is $25+7n-3\binom{n}{2}+2\binom{n}{3}-2\binom{n}{4}$. This sequence has generating function $\frac{25}{1-z}+\frac{7z}{(1-z)^2}-\frac{3z^2}{(1-z)^3}+\frac{2z^3}{(1-z)^4}-\frac{2z^4}{(1-z)^5}$.

I doubt this matches what you got, because the highest power of $(1-z)^{-1}$ is different. My comment on the OP noted WA gave me a different generating function anyway (which, by the same logic, probably doesn't match the above either). Further, this $k$th-difference technique predicts the next term is $40$, not $42$ (although WA gave me $42$ as the next term as well).